# Does a multicast source have to be connected to the RP for Cisco PIM-SM to work?

Tags: cisco, routing, multicast, pim

I'm fairly new to networking in general, but I need to develop a 4 point mesh with redundant paths routing multicast from point A to points B and C. I've already setup the mesh and have network redistribution with OSPF and PIM-SM running and working (99% anyways... I think), however, I'm having a issue where if a source is connected to any router that is not the RP (where the RP is also the gateway for the source) the multicast is not being distributed.

As I understand it, the router receiving the multicast should be either notifying the RP that he has the source for that group so the RP can build the SPT or should be unicasting the stream to the RP for it's redistribution, but there's no traffic going from this router towards the RP.

In my lab, I'm using 4x catalyst 3550 switches with the EMI firmware to enable the multicast routing. I've set it up using the autorp feature (I only intend to have a single RP) in case we later on decide to add more redundancy to the design.

Is there anything I need to do on the non-rp router to tell him "if you see this multicast IP originating within one of your networks relay it to the RP" or should this be happening on its own?

RP:

```
version 12.2
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname PT
!
no logging console
!
username EDITED privilege 15 secret 5 EDITED
aaa new-model
!
!
!
!
!
aaa session-id common
ip subnet-zero
ip routing
no ip domain-lookup
!
!
ip multicast-routing
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
ip ssh version 2
!
!
!
!
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 172.30.255.0 255.255.255.255
 ip pim sparse-mode
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 description CNMG
 no switchport
 ip address 172.30.2.1 255.255.255.252
 ip pim sparse-mode
 ip ospf cost 100
 load-interval 30
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 description TT
 no switchport
 ip address 172.30.2.17 255.255.255.252
 ip pim sparse-mode
 ip ospf cost 1000
 load-interval 30
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
 description WinPC_Server_Source
 switchport access vlan 2
 switchport mode access
 load-interval 30
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport mode dynamic desirable
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 switchport mode dynamic desirable
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 192.168.20.254 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan2
 ip address 172.30.100.6 255.255.255.248
 ip pim sparse-mode
!
router ospf 100
 log-adjacency-changes
 redistribute connected metric-type 1 subnets
 network 172.30.2.0 0.0.0.3 area 0
 network 172.30.2.16 0.0.0.3 area 0
!
ip default-gateway 172.30.0.254
ip classless
ip http server
ip http secure-server
!
ip pim autorp listener
ip pim send-rp-announce Loopback0 scope 12 group-list 1
ip pim send-rp-discovery scope 12
!
access-list 1 permit 239.10.10.0 0.0.0.255
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
line vty 0 4
 privilege level 15
line vty 5 15
!
end
```

Source:

```
version 12.2
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec localtime show-timezone
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Cumberland
!
no logging console
!
username EDITED secret 5 EDITED
aaa new-model
!
!
!
!
!
aaa session-id common
clock timezone POS -4
ip subnet-zero
ip routing
no ip domain-lookup
!
!
ip multicast-routing
no ip igmp snooping
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 172.30.255.2 255.255.255.255
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 description TT
 no switchport
 ip address 172.30.2.10 255.255.255.252
 ip pim sparse-mode
 ip ospf cost 200
 load-interval 30
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 description CNMG
 no switchport
 ip address 172.30.2.5 255.255.255.252
 ip pim sparse-mode
 ip ospf cost 100
 load-interval 30
!
! int 3-47 not in use
!
interface FastEthernet0/48
 switchport access vlan 2
 switchport mode access
 load-interval 30
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport mode dynamic desirable
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 switchport mode dynamic desirable
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 192.168.22.254 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan2
 ip address 172.30.100.22 255.255.255.248
 ip pim sparse-mode
!
router ospf 100
 log-adjacency-changes
 redistribute connected metric-type 1 subnets
 network 172.30.2.4 0.0.0.3 area 0
 network 172.30.2.8 0.0.0.3 area 0
!
ip classless
ip http server
ip http secure-server
!
ip pim autorp listener
ip pim send-rp-discovery scope 12
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
line vty 0 4
 privilege level 15
line vty 5 15
!
end
```

**UPDATE:**
Here's a diagram describing my topology:

[image: Topology Diagram]

**UPDATE #2:**
I'm adding the **show** data requested by Ron in the comments:

```
Cumberland>show ip mroute
IP Multicast Routing Table
Flags: D - Dense, S - Sparse, B - Bidir Group, s - SSM Group, C - Connected,
       L - Local, P - Pruned, R - RP-bit set, F - Register flag,
       T - SPT-bit set, J - Join SPT, M - MSDP created entry,
       X - Proxy Join Timer Running, A - Candidate for MSDP Advertisement,
       U - URD, I - Received Source Specific Host Report,
       Z - Multicast Tunnel, z - MDT-data group sender,
       Y - Joined MDT-data group, y - Sending to MDT-data group
       V - RD & Vector, v - Vector
Outgoing interface flags: H - Hardware switched, A - Assert winner
 Timers: Uptime/Expires
 Interface state: Interface, Next-Hop or VCD, State/Mode

(*, 239.10.10.1), 2d02h/stopped, RP 172.30.255.0, flags: SJC
  Incoming interface: FastEthernet0/2, RPF nbr 172.30.2.6
  Outgoing interface list:
    Vlan2, Forward/Sparse, 2d02h/00:02:45, H

(172.30.100.5, 239.10.10.1), 2d02h/00:02:59, flags: JT
  Incoming interface: FastEthernet0/2, RPF nbr 172.30.2.6
  Outgoing interface list:
    Vlan2, Forward/Sparse, 2d02h/00:02:45, H

(*, 224.0.1.39), 2d02h/stopped, RP 0.0.0.0, flags: DCL
  Incoming interface: Null, RPF nbr 0.0.0.0
  Outgoing interface list:
    Vlan2, Forward/Sparse, 2d02h/00:00:00
    FastEthernet0/2, Forward/Sparse, 2d02h/00:00:00
    FastEthernet0/1, Forward/Sparse, 2d02h/00:00:00

(172.30.255.0, 224.0.1.39), 2d02h/00:02:48, flags: LT
  Incoming interface: FastEthernet0/2, RPF nbr 172.30.2.6
  Outgoing interface list:
    FastEthernet0/1, Prune/Sparse, 00:02:14/00:00:45
    Vlan2, Forward/Sparse, 2d02h/00:00:00

(*, 224.0.1.40), 2d02h/stopped, RP 0.0.0.0, flags: DCL
  Incoming interface: Null, RPF nbr 0.0.0.0
  Outgoing interface list:
    FastEthernet0/2, Forward/Sparse, 2d02h/00:00:00
    FastEthernet0/1, Forward/Sparse, 2d02h/00:00:00
    Vlan2, Forward/Sparse, 2d02h/00:00:00

(172.30.2.10, 224.0.1.40), 00:01:37/00:01:22, flags: L
  Incoming interface: FastEthernet0/1, RPF nbr 0.0.0.0
  Outgoing interface list:
    Vlan2, Forward/Sparse, 00:01:37/00:00:00
    FastEthernet0/2, Forward/Sparse, 00:01:37/00:00:00

(172.30.2.5, 224.0.1.40), 00:01:37/00:01:22, flags: L
  Incoming interface: FastEthernet0/2, RPF nbr 0.0.0.0
  Outgoing interface list:
    Vlan2, Forward/Sparse, 00:01:37/00:00:00
    FastEthernet0/1, Forward/Sparse, 00:01:37/00:00:00

(172.30.2.17, 224.0.1.40), 2d02h/00:02:16, flags: LT
  Incoming interface: FastEthernet0/1, RPF nbr 172.30.2.9
  Outgoing interface list:
    Vlan2, Forward/Sparse, 2d02h/00:00:00
    FastEthernet0/2, Prune/Sparse, 00:01:50/00:01:09

(172.30.2.1, 224.0.1.40), 2d02h/00:02:16, flags: LT
  Incoming interface: FastEthernet0/2, RPF nbr 172.30.2.6
  Outgoing interface list:
    FastEthernet0/1, Forward/Sparse, 2d02h/00:00:00
    Vlan2, Forward/Sparse, 2d02h/00:00:00

Cumberland>sh ip pim neighbor
PIM Neighbor Table
Mode: B - Bidir Capable, DR - Designated Router, N - Default DR Priority,
      P - Proxy Capable, S - State Refresh Capable
Neighbor          Interface                Uptime/Expires    Ver   DR
Address                                                            Prio/Mode
172.30.2.9        FastEthernet0/1          2d02h/00:01:42    v2    1 / S P
172.30.2.6        FastEthernet0/2          2d02h/00:01:16    v2    1 / DR S P
Cumberland>sh ip pim rp map
PIM Group-to-RP Mappings
This system is an RP-mapping agent

Group(s) 239.10.10.0/24
  RP 172.30.255.0 (?), v2v1
    Info source: 172.30.255.0 (?), elected via Auto-RP
         Uptime: 2d02h, expires: 00:02:14
Cumberland>
```

Comment: Yes, you need to tell the router where the RP is.  Can you post your config(s)?

Comment: Sure, I'll paste-bin them in a sec, but isn't that part of the autorp feature's role?

Comment: Yes, if you've configured it correctly.  That's why we want to see the configs.

Comment: Where the remote source is: http://pastebin.com/9JvPh0FW, 
RP: http://pastebin.com/kQD9jGGt,

Comment: I'm not sure why you are enabling PIM on the VLANs for the source or clients. PIM is a router-to-router protocol. IGMP is the host to router protocol. You can configure IGMP to join a group on the router interfaces for the groups you want to test. Cisco has a pretty good document about this, [Configuring IP Multicast Routing](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/ip/configuration/guide/fipr_c/1cfmulti.html#wp1000889), with a drawing which explains where the various protocols go.

Comment: The VLAN interface has PIM enabled because I'm using it as the gateway for the VLAN, so I need the traffic to be routed out of said VLAN. On all VLANs IGMP Snooping is enabled by default, though I can disable it and try to setup full IGMP as per your suggestion, but just to clarify, are you then saying I need to do static joins to each group? As mentioned before I'm not a networking expert by any means, this project just happened to fall on me for reasons....

Comment: Can you post "show ip mroute" "sh ip pim neighbor" and "sh ip pim rp map" from the remote router?

Comment: Hi @RonTrunk I've added an update with the data you asked for

Comment: PIM is only needed between routers. If the VLAN is for end-users with no other routers, you don't need PIM on the VLAN.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

See the drawing about where PIM is between routers, and IGMP is between the router and the hosts. IGMP snooping is a switch command which is not necessary for the operation of multicast, but it lets the switch snoop on the IGMP messages between the hosts and router. Even without IGMP snooping, you still need IGMP; the multicast listener application sends an IGMP message to the router to tell it to start sending the multicast group out the router interface. All that IGMP snooping does is to let the switch target the specific ports instead of flooding all the ports. The drawing shows the older CGMP instead of IGMP snooping, but the purpose is the same.

[image]

As soon as the host application wants to listen to a multicast group, it sends an IGMP join message for a group to the router. The router will then set up the multicast forwarding and send the multicasts to the interface. The router will periodically send IGMP queries out the interface to see if any hosts are still interested in receiving this multicast group. If it gets no replies in the time period, it will stop sending the multicast group to the interface.

You don't specify what the source type is, nor the destination application. You may have a problem with one of the other. If the source application is sending the multicasts, you may need to check the target application. You can use the `ip igmp join-group <group-address>` interface command on your routers aid in your testing.

**Notes:**

You are setting both the RP and the source as the RP mapping agent (`ip pim send-rp-discovery scope 12`). You only need to do this on the RP since the RP can be the mapping agent.

You should enter your loopback as the interface-id for the RP mapping agent:

```
ip pim send-rp-discovery Loopback0 scope 12
```

You shouldn't have `ip default-gateway 172.30.0.254` in a router. A router should have routes delivered by OSPF.

You are redistributing connected routes, but you have explicit network statement for two of those routes. You should pick one way or the other. Instead of `redistribute connected`, you should probably use a broad network statement so that your routes aren't external routes:

```
router ospf 100
 log-adjacency-changes
 passive-interface default
 no passive-interface FastEthernet0/1
 no passive-interface FastEthernet0/3
 network 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 area 0
!
```

Double-check unicast routing, in particular, make sure that the source router has a route to the loopback of the RP.

Answer (score 0):

After trying extensively with all that was discussed here I turned to wiresharking the traffic and as it turns out there was a bug on my source that was causing the stream to be produced with a TTL of 0 (regardless of the GUI setting).